# Extending Java search results in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on a [Pig plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse). Pig allows you to call Java methods from .pig files, and what I'd like to do is to extend the default Java "find references" (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+G</kbd>) so that it detects such calls from Pig to Java.

I found a command that seems appropriate - `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.search.references.in.workspace`  and added a handler for it. This handler gets called whenever a user activates "find references" using the default key binding and my plugin's editor is the active editor (i.e., on a .pig file). However, when a Java file is the active editor, the original handler gets called.

One thing that might be useful is a reference to another Eclipse plugin with this functionality implemented, so that calls from Java from non-Java files are detected by the default find references functionality.